# How to use courier to refill bottle/ bottle crow

Tags: dota-2

I have seen people using the courier to replenish their bottle without having to leave their lane, how do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Send the courier to yourself (select it and right click somewhere near your hero).
- Drag the bottle from your inventory onto the courier.
- Send the courier back to base.
- Deliver the bottle back to your hero.

And don't forget that a bottle can be refilled by picking up a [rune](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Runes).

Comment: How do you give it to the courier though? When I try to drag it onto the courier all that happens is I get it back straight away...

Comment: Alternatively you can drop the bottle on the ground, right click it with the courier and then hold SHIFT and click your hotkey to get the courier to go back to base. Just make sure you drop the bottle somewhere safe ;) I do this in the mid-lane.

Comment: @FlightOfGrey You must be doing it wrong. Make sure to give the bottle to the courier when it's not commanded to "give you items". Otherwise what happens is that you will give your courier the bottle before it finishes this command, thus giving you the bottle back. Also, after the courier has the bottle either manually move the courier to base or order it to using hotkeys.

Comment: @FlightOfGrey Left click and drag the Bottle to the courier.

Comment: Must have been what I was doing thanks Kotsu and everyone else for the tips, will give it a go when I next play a game. I don't usually play a mid hero but I got caught out the other day and realised I had no idea how to do it. So thanks.

Comment: Be carefull, the fountain got a weird range and it can happen that the bottle is not refilled. Be sure the courrier goes close enough to the fountain (especially if your teamates use it at the same time)

Comment: This is rather slow; you can put the empty bottle on the ground (somewhere safe without the enemy seeing it!), then command your chicken to pick it up and shift-queue go back to base and bring items, you can then fully concentrate on your lane again and the chicken will do everything on its own. Just remember to activate the speed boost *after* it picked up the empty bottle to compensate the movement speed loss.